# Can PHP pointers to POST and GET be isset?

Tags: php, http-post

So for example I have the following code.

```
<?PHP
$a = "key";
$b = "val";
$val = & $_POST[$a.$b];

if(isset($val))
  echo "Is this valid ? What if I removed the & in front of $val?";
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes its not working. I wanted to get pointer not set it to actual variable if possible

Comment: don't think your code can run at all you not even opening the if statement and for a variable it is better to do if (!empty($val)){ and what is that = & $_POST and i would use $c=$a.$b; then $val=$_POST[$c];

Comment: That I know, I would like to check if the variable is set not if it has a value, and create a pointer to that $_POST

Comment: Sorry guys I was running a broken php version. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$val = isset($_POST[$a.$b]) ? $_POST[$a.$b] : null;
```

This will set the value if it exists, or set it null if it doesn't.
The & assigns the variable by reference. What this means is if you change the value of $val, $_POST[$a.$b] will also be updated. So it isn't really necessary.

Comment: I just want to get the pointer to $_POST[$a.$b] not the value.

Comment: isset($_POST[$a.$b]) is enough to tell if it is there or not. If you want the value to change when you alter $val, keep the & when you assign it.